# Issue with Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have just thought of working on Windows App Development with a Friend of mine, but before I could start I'm experiencing an issue with Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone while Creating a New Project.

> Whenever I try making a Project, a window pops up saying “Member not
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))”

[image]

Please provide directions to its Fix, and also do consider me as Newbie =p
PS: I'm using Windows 8.1 64 Bit

Comment: Do you have multiple installations of Visual Studio? Can you try to repair your installation of Visual Studio?

Comment: do you have the latest versions of vs2012?

Comment: Yes, I think i had Visual Studio Express 2012 for WINDOWS DESKTOP but the issue persists with the one for WINDOWS PHONE.